# How to stretch div to full height with flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

How do I stretch the divs with a yellow background to full height? It should cover up the green but it is not working. I tried adding `height: 100%` on it but then it adds up the height from the search bar?

https://jsfiddle.net/nuy20j1h/

```css
.block {
  width: 80%; 
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.sidebar {
  height: 600px;
  width: 25%; 
  background: red;
}

.home {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: flex-start;
  width: 75%;
  background: green;
}

.search-bar {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 25px;
  background: blue;
}

.content-wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: flex-stretch;
}

.content,
.single {
  width: 50%;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="sidebar">sidebar</div>
  <div class="home">
    <div class="search-bar">search bar</div>
    <div class="content-wrap">
      <div class="content">lorem ipsum</div>
      <div class="single">test</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `height:100%;`  makes the yellow part covers the green part, not the blue (search bar) part. This is not what you want?

Comment: Nope, it should be the same height as the sidebar.

Comment: @twoam do you want items to still remain in the middle ?

Comment: Height of the side bar is 600px, then you need to give height to both the search bar and the green / yellow part that sums up to 600px.

Comment: @Zvezdas1989 No it should just cover up the green without setting a specific height.

Comment: Or define a outer container with a height of 600px; and set the height of the sidebar as 100% too;

Comment: @ildflue That doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in other answers, there is one main issue here:

- `flex-direction:  column;`, which I added to `home`, to enable the usage of flex properties instead of `height`, to make the `.content-wrap` fill the available space left in `home`

That will make the `.search-bar` and `.content-wrap` stack vertical, and enable the use of `flex: 1` on `.content-wrap`, which will make it fill the remaining space/height.

---

So even if you got answers already, and since there are some properties with wrong value, or not needed, I decided to post an answer to clarify the changes made.

See my notes made in the CSS for further clarifications and what I changed.

Stack snippet

```css
.block {
  width: 80%; 
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.sidebar {
  height: 600px;
  width: 25%; 
  background: red;
}

.home {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:  column;      /*  added  */
  /*flex-wrap: wrap;                removed, not needed  */
  /*align-items: flex-start;        removed, items should fill parent's,
                                    in this changed case, width  */
  width: 75%;
  background: green;
}

.search-bar {
  /*width: 100%;                    not needed, default for column
                                    item is to fill parent width as
                                    its "align-items" is "stretch"  */
  padding: 25px;
  background: blue;
}

.content-wrap {
  flex: 1;                      /*  added, take the remaining space left
                                    left of its parent (height in this case)  */
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  /*width: 100%;                    not needed, default for column
                                    item is to fill parent width as
                                    its "align-items" is "stretch"  */

  /*align-items: flex-stretch;      wrong value, should be "stretch",
                                    though since that is the default,
                                    it is not needed  */
}

.content,
.single {
  width: 50%;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="sidebar">sidebar</div>
  <div class="home">
    <div class="search-bar">search bar</div>
    <div class="content-wrap">
      <div class="content">lorem ipsum</div>
      <div class="single">test</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

First you should add a style reset, I'm using this now `* {}` as you can se below. The trick here is to run `flex-direction: column;` on `.home` and you can tell `.content-wrap` to take up the rest of that space after the search with `flex-grow: 1;`

`box-sizing: border-box;` is, if you add let's say `width: 200px;` to a element, and add `padding: 20px;`, the element will stay 200px with the padding included. If you don't have that, it will take up 200px + 40px.

if you want the fiddle, [here it is](https://jsfiddle.net/nuy20j1h/14/)

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.block {
  width: 80%; 
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.sidebar {
  height: 600px;
  width: 25%; 
  background: red;
}

.home {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: flex-start;
  width: 75%;
  background: green;
}

.search-bar {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 25px;
  background: blue;
}

.content-wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: flex-stretch;
}

.content,
.single {
  width: 50%;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="sidebar">sidebar</div>
  <div class="home">
    <div class="search-bar">search bar</div>
    <div class="content-wrap">
      <div class="content">lorem ipsum</div>
      <div class="single">test</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Adding a general reset like that is a really bad way, and will break many elements natural paddings/margins.

Answer (score 0):

`flex-direction: column;` is your friend. Here is a reworked fiddle of your code: https://jsfiddle.net/vsjktmms/1/

Using the same HTML structure you provided:

```
.block {
  display: flex;
  width: 80%; 
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: gray;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.sidebar {
  width: 25%;
  height: 600px;
  background-color: red;
}

.home {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: stretch;
  width: 75%;
  background-color: green;
}

.search-bar {
  padding: 25px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.content-wrap {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: pink;
}

.content,
.single {
  width: 50%;
  background: yellow;
}
```